# Adding new apps to django

Tags: python, django

I have followed the guidelines for starting up learning django, but i have a question. if I want to add a new app onto the `polls` app they instructed, called `poll2`, can I just copy + paste the polls folder? (this is for example if I want to make an identical app, with same functionality). Is there anything else special i need to do, other than make `admin.py` load `poll2` along with polls?

Comment: Why do you need to copy it at all if its just going to do the same exact thing?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason people say "copy paste is evil"

However if you're willing to, you just need to make sure to change references (if they exist) to `poll` inside your new app to `poll2`.

Because e.g. in poll/somefile.py there may be an absolute import in this form:

```
from poll import someting
```

Which isn't going to do well if that gets copied into `poll2` app and the goal is to use `poll2` and not use `poll` from `poll2`

And the list of things to rename from `poll` to `poll2` goes on and on. E.g. templates in `poll/templates/poll/something.html`, and perhaps URL namespaces, etc

Bottom line, doable, just make sure absolute references are renamed to `poll2`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. As long as your apps live in the different folders, they are completely independent apps for Django. Just make sure they both are loaded in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

* Catch #1: If you have the identical template tags files, rename them so they would become `polls_tags.py` and `polls2_tags.py`.

* Catch #2: Don't forget to rename your templates so that `templates/polls/index.html' becomes 'templates/polls2/index.html`.